# Oracle SQL set sql values to variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare dates between the same table. I wanted to store each value to a variable and compare the if there is a month difference between the two dates.

Here is my table structure:

**TABLE NAME: SYSTEMPARAM

SEQNO - INT primary key

SYSTEMDATE - DATE**

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
var startdate = "SELECT SYSTEMDATE FROM SYSTEMPARAM WHERE SEQNO = '1'";
var enddate = "SELECT SYSTEMDATE FROM SYSTEMPARAM WHERE SEQNO = '2'";

if(MONTHS_BETWEEN(startdate , enddate ){

  //Conditions here
}
```

I want to compare if there is a month difference between two sql statement.

Comment: After you "compare", what do you need to do with the information you obtained? From what you described so far, everything can be done in plain SQL (so, no "if statement" and no "assignment to variables"). You seem to want to approach your problem from a procedural point of view, which is not the SQL philosophy. Best to describe the full problem, so that we can help you with a good solution to it (rather than trying to hammer nails with a butter knife).

Answer (score 0):

"Procedural" means PL/SQL. So, do it that way.

Just to know what dates represent:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * From systemparam;

     SEQNO SYSTEMDATE
---------- ----------
         1 04.04.2021
         2 05.04.2021
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_startdate systemparam.systemdate%type;
  3    l_enddate   systemparam.systemdate%type;
  4  begin
  5    select s.systemdate
  6      into l_startdate
  7      from systemparam s
  8      where s.seqno = 1;
  9
 10    select s.systemdate
 11      into l_enddate
 12      from systemparam s
 13      where s.seqno = 2;
 14
 15    if months_between(l_enddate, l_startdate) > 0 then
 16       dbms_output.put_line('Dates are not equal');
 17    end if;
 18  end;
 19  /
Dates are not equal

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Though, if there are any "months" between these two dates ("0.01" months between is still "months between", although *tiny*), then they aren't equal so it is maybe more obvious to use `if l_enddate <> l_startdate then` instead, isn't it? Also, check another option of the `SELECT` statement:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_startdate systemparam.systemdate%type;
  3    l_enddate   systemparam.systemdate%type;
  4  begin
  5    select max(case when s.seqno = 1 then s.systemdate end),
  6           max(case when s.seqno = 2 then s.systemdate end)
  7      into l_startdate,
  8           l_enddate
  9    from systemparam s;
 10
 11    if l_enddate <> l_startdate then
 12       dbms_output.put_line('Dates are not equal');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /
Dates are not equal

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---